# how to connect virtualbox to docker toolbox

Tags: docker, virtualization

so I just install docker toolbox but I always get this error message that's says :

> this computer doesn't haver VT-X/AMD-v enabled

I don't have hyper v because I'm running on **windows 10 home** edition

**so how can I use docker with oracle virtualbox instead ??**

Answer (score 0):

Look at your system's BIOS, you should enable virtualization there.